# Excel Ranking function

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can't find specific answer to this problem on other posts.

I have a table with a list of vehicle registrations and a list of times for those vehicles. I want to give each row a rank based on the time allocated to a vehicle registration.  Each registration will appear multiple times with a different time of day alongside it.

I want the earliest in the day for a vehicle to be rank 1, second earliest rank 2 ... etc.

Screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Great, well worded question +1

Comment: I think it would be easier using VBA for this. Is it ok for You, or you want other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be achieved with COUNTIFS function:

`=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$8,B2,$C$2:$C$8,"<="&C2)`
[image]

Comment: Elegant! Very nice solution.

Comment: Very clever, that will do nicely.  Thankyou muchly.